# Asset Management App - How do I filter a collection of lists displayed in a PowerApps gallery using a comboBox of people names?

Tags: list, powerapps-canvas, sharepoint-list-filter

I am trying to find a way to filter a collection of SharePoint Lists displayed in a PowerApps Gallery using a ComboBox dropdown. This ComboBox dropdown gets data from another sharepoint lists for single user selection. I would like to select a specific person's name and see only data for that specific person.

How can I do this ?

Thank you.

Omar

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter function on the Gallery datasource to achieve this.
Use the syntax like -

```
Filter(colGallery, 'Created By'.Email = ComboBoxName.Selected.User.Email)
```

`colGallery` is the list item collection used to display records in the gallery.

Hope it gives you some idea.